# JS regexp to match special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a JavaScript regexp for this string: `![]()`. It needs to be an exact match, though, so:

```
`!()[]`      // No match
hello!()[]   // No match
!()[]hello   // No Match
!()[]        // Match
 !()[]       // Match (with a whitespace before and/or after)
```

I tried this: `\b![]()\b`. It works for words, like `\bhello\b`, but not for those characters.

Comment: What if `"hello ![]() world"`? Matches or not?

Answer (score 3):

The characters specified are control characters and need to be escaped also user \s if you want to match whitespace. Try the following

```
\s?!(?:\[\]\(\)|\(\)\[\])\s?
```

EDIT: Added a capture group to extract `![]()` if needed

EDIT2: I missed that you wanted order independant for `[]` and `()` I've added it in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MfFAd/3/

Comment: This has a small issue. Your second edit worked perfectly, but it did not account for `!`; your last edit, though, creates two elements and a white space before the element.

Comment: OK, last edit almost works, but leaves a preceding space. Console output: `" ![]()"`

Comment: I depreped and posted the wrong link. Anyways to remove the space you'll have to add a capture group around `!(?:\[\]\(\)|\(\)\[\])` and then use `out[1]` to get the captured result

Comment: Also, you were right earlier. They are order dependent. It was a typo. It always has to be `![]()`. There's never any `!()[]`

Comment: Ah okay well I'll leave the answer like this in any case, I trust you can change it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This matches your example:

```
\s*!\[\]\(\)\s*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Though the match also includes the spaces before and after `!()[]`.

I think `\b` does not work here because `![]()` is not a word. Check out this [quote from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> \b - Matches a word boundary. A word boundary matches the position where a word character is not followed or preceeded by another word-character. Note that a matched word boundary is not included in the match. In other words, the length of a matched word boundary is zero.

Comment: Sorry, The order dependence was a typo on my part. Round brackets are ALWAYS before square brackets.

Comment: THat simplifies it a lot. Edited.

Comment: The only issue i have with this is that it captures the spaces around the string. I want the console output to be `["![]()"]` and not `[" ![]()"]`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MfFAd/4/

Comment: You could capture spaces `(\s)` and [include them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex) in replace or whatever you're doing

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a function for convenience :

```
function find(r, s) {
    return (s.match(r) || []).slice(-1);
}
```

The following regular expression accepts only the searched string and whitespaces :

```
var r = /^\s*(!\[\]\(\))\s*$/;
find(r, '![]() ');      // ["![]()"]
find(r, '!()[] ');      // []
find(r, 'hello ![]()'); // []
```

This one searches a sub-string surrounded by whitespaces or string boundaries :

```
var r = /(?:^|\s)(!\[\]\(\))(?:\s|$)/;
find(r, '![]() ');      // ["![]()"]
find(r, 'hello ![]()'); // ["![]()"]
find(r, 'hello![]()');  // []
```

Answer (score 0):

To match all characters except letters and numbers you can use this regex

```
/[^A-Z0-9]/gi
```

g - search global [ mean whole text, not just first match ]
i -case insensitive

to remove any other sign for example `. and ,`

```
/[^A-Z0-9\.\,]/gi
```

In order to match exact string you need to group it and global parameter

```
/(\!\[\]\(\))/g
```

so it will search for all matches